# remote database not updating after entering fields

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio

I had made a registration page of the following code & when ever i run the code for enter data i am getting no errors , but when i refresh my remote database the field/information is not updated, I don't know where i am making mistake...

Here i am calling out my connection string from my web.config file.

```
     public string GetConnectionString()
{
    //sets the connection string from your web config file "ConnString" is the name of your Connection String
    return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RN_DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
}
```

below is the code, i am getting no errors in it but my remote database is been not updated. Iam doing something wrong..????

private void ExecuteInsert(string FName, string LName, string EID, string Password, string RPassword,
        string Organization, string WPhone, string CPhone, string Country,
        string City, string State, string Address)
    {

```
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
    string sql = "INSERT INTO RN_DB.dbo.Table (FName, LName, EID, Password, RPassword, Organization, WPhone,CPhone,Country, City, State, Address) VALUES "
                + " (@FName,@LName,@EID,@Password,@RPassword,@Organization,@WPhone,@CPhone,@Country,@City,@State,@Addess)";

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[12];
        //param[0] = new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
        param[0] = new SqlParameter("@FName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
        param[1] = new SqlParameter("@LName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
        param[2] = new SqlParameter("@EID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
        param[3] = new SqlParameter("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
        param[4] = new SqlParameter("@RPassword", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
        param[5] = new SqlParameter("@Organization", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
        param[6] = new SqlParameter("@WPhone", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
        param[7] = new SqlParameter("@CPhone", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
        param[8] = new SqlParameter("@Country", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
        param[9] = new SqlParameter("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
        param[10] = new SqlParameter("@State", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
        param[11] = new SqlParameter("@Address", SqlDbType.Text);

        param[0].Value = FName;
        param[1].Value = LName;
        param[2].Value = EID;
        param[3].Value = Password;
        param[4].Value = RPassword;
        param[5].Value = Organization;
        param[6].Value = WPhone;
        param[7].Value = CPhone;
        param[8].Value = City;
        param[9].Value = Country;
        param[10].Value = State;
        param[11].Value = Address;

        for (int i = 0; i < param.Length; i++)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param[i]);
        }

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
    {
        string msg = "Insert Error:";
        msg += ex.Message;


    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Pass.Text == RPass.Text)
    {
        Guid newGUID = Guid.NewGuid();
        //call the method to execute insert to the database
        ExecuteInsert(FName.Text,
                          LName.Text,
                          EID.Text, Pass.Text, RPass.Text, Org.Text, WPhone.Text, CPhone.Text,
                          Country.Text,
                          City.Text, State.Text, Address.Text);
        Response.Write("Record was successfully added!");

    }

    else
    {
        Response.Write("Password's didnot match");
        Pass.Focus();
    }
```

Comment: you aren't doing anything with your error message.  Throw an error in your catch statement and that may give some indication as to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have an error message, but you lose it here:

```
catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
{
    string msg = "Insert Error:";
    msg += ex.Message;


}
```

Your `msg` local variable gets the message you need, but you do not show it anywhere. You need to do something: either show it somewhere or throw the exception further.

Comment: Thanks mate i just threw new exception below that line & got the error. now i am rectifying it..